# Error when deserializing JSON from League of Legends API

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to use RiotGames Api. I have JSON data and I need to deserialize this JSON to c# classes but I get an error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WFALeagueOfLegendsAPI.Heroes]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'datas.Aatrox', line 1, position 85.'

My Classes:

```
    public class JsonRoot
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string format { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public List<Heroes> datas { get; set; }
    }

    public class Heroes
    {
        public HeroesData Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class HeroesData
    {
        public string version { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public HeroImage image { get; set; }
    }

    public class HeroImage
    {
        public string full { get; set; }
        public string sprite { get; set; }
        public string group { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return full;
        }
    }
```

C# Code:

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json");

json = json.Replace("data", "datas");
JsonRoot jr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonRoot>(json); // this line has the error
```

Comment: Usually Newtsoft handles array to list fine but, as an easy hack just change Heros list to an array

Comment: The property is named `data` not `datas`. Rename the property or use `JsonPropertyAttribute`: `[JsonProperty(PropertyName="data")]`. Never use `Replace` to reformat data.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen i try your advice but same error. If i use replace for data error fixed but return null :/

Comment: The problem is that the json data is "malformed". `data` is a `json object` and not an `array of json objects`. You are trying to deserialize the json object as a json array. `data` consists of several properties, each named after the user id. I.e. `Aatrox`, `Ahri`, etc. You'd need to create a new class for each of these properties or use custom parsing.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen I understand now. type, format and version is unnecessary for me, i need just data. how do i get it?

Comment: That, my friend, is a too broad of a question.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen - the JSON is not "malformed" - it validates just fine.  Try it at https://jsonlint.com/.  Also, you do not need a different class for each hero, nor do you need custom parsing here.  Using a dictionary will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are using a `List<Heroes>` for the `data`, but that property is not an array in the JSON.  You need to use a `Dictionary<string, HeroesData>` instead.  The heroes' names will be the keys of the dictionary.  Also, if you want to use a different name for a particular property in your class than what is in the JSON, you can use a `[JsonProperty]` attribute, as shown below.  It's not really a good idea to use `string.Replace` to try to change the JSON to suit your classes, because you could end up replacing things you did not intend.

```
public class JsonRoot
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string format { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Dictionary<string, HeroesData> heroes { get; set; }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kuKSrk